# symfony 3.4 set prod environment

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, virtualhost

I upgrade symfony 2.8 to 3.4

after upgrade and upload to production server in mydomain.com? I check mode and it's dev not prod.

This is my Htacces :

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# startpage (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewritting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php5 .phar

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /


    RewriteRule ^web/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC]



    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the startpage because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the startpage to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

and this is apapche vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/home/app/symfony"
  ServerName app.com
  ServerAlias  www.app.com
  <Directory "/home/app/symfony">
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I add 
     
        SetEnv SYMFONY_ENV prod
            allow from all
            Options +Indexes
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted

but still see dev in mydomain.com/ - How switch to prod ?

in profiler :

Symfony Configuration
3.4.8
Symfony version
app
Application name
dev
Environment

Request Headers: 
APP_ENV 
"prod"

SYMFONY_ENV 
"prod"

I have also clear cache :

> rm -rf var/cache/*;
>
> rm -rf var/logs/*
>
> php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod
>
> php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=dev

ok found solution - simple error - apache vhost is set to symfony/ not symfony/web/ - if i change to web it work.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Try clearing cache.

Comment: How do you "see dev in mydomain.com"?

Comment: Can you paste you `app.php` file ?

Comment: i see tollbar, i see app_dev.php file is used, i see enn: dev in toolbar / configuration

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `composer require symfony/dotenv` then run `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader` and `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug` on the production server.

Comment: Also after you install symfony/dotenv you may need to edit .env in the root directory of your project (make sure env is set to prod).